# VNC SERVER source/app for non-jailbroken iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have looked and looked and cannot find an answer. I am looking for an open source vnc **server** for the iphone. I would like to deploy it to my device, and not install it via jailbreaking/cydia. [I'm not looking for a tv-out option (I know that exists), nor a VNC client. Also not looking for screen mirroring (http://code.google.com/p/iphoneos-screen-mirroring/).]

Alternate approach: If you KNOW one doesn't exist at the moment: I know veency is out there to be downloaded through Cydia, and I could use something like iResign to sign the ipa with my dev certificates but if I have to go this route how would I get the ipa and it's dependencies without jailbreaking? And could the dependency debs even be installed with iResign?

**I've been pulling my hair out over this, so any help of any kind will be greatly appreciate. Thank you for your time!**

Answer (score 3):

A VNC server on an unjailbroken iPhone isn't possible. Multitasking is strictly limited to a particular few cases - you certainly wouldn't be able to shoehorn something so hefty as a VNC server into it.

Comment: It's possible, as shown in this video: https://youtu.be/Y1TY5Px1718